# How can i concatenate three 2D arrays which contain hue, saturation and intensity values in their respective arrays and display that as an image?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image-processing

I am new to image processing and python. As you can see from my code, i managed to convert my RGB image to HSI by using the different formulas that i found.

I stored the values of hue, saturation and intensity in three different arrays. That is also in the code down below. How can i concatenate those three arrays and display the concatenated image as an image?

```
import math 
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("D:\\Texture analysis\\trees-clolorful-aerial-view-wallpaper.jpg")

rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')

row, col = img.size

print(row, col)

i = j = 0

satValue = 0 
inValue = 0 
hueValue = 0

squareValue = 0

hueArray = [[0 for x in range(row)] for y in range(col)]
satArray = [[0 for x in range(row)] for y in range(col)] 
inArray = [[0 for x in range(row)] for y in range(col)]

division = 0 
denominator = 0 
numerator = 0 
radAngle = 0 
degAngle = 0 
product = 0 
sqr = 0 
count = 0 
uCount = 0

while i < row:
    j = 0
    while j < col:
        red, green, blue = rgb_img.getpixel((i, j))

        hRed = sRed = iRed = red
        hGreen = sGreen = iGreen = green
        hBlue = sBlue = iBlue = blue

# =========================Saturation Calculation==============================
        if sRed == 0 and sGreen == 0 and sBlue == 0:
            satValue = 0
            satArray[i][j] = 0
        else:
            if (sRed < sGreen) and (sRed < sBlue):
                satValue = 1 - (((3) * (sRed)) / (sRed + sGreen + sBlue))
                satArray[i][j] = satValue
    #            print(satValue)
            elif (sGreen < sRed) and (sGreen < sBlue):
                satValue = 1 - (((3) * (sGreen)) / (sRed + sGreen + sBlue))
                satArray[i][j] = satValue
    #            print(satValue)
            else:
                satValue = 1 - (((3) * (sBlue)) / (sRed + sGreen + sBlue))
                satArray[i][j] = satValue
    #            print(satValue)
# =============================================================================

# ==========================Intensity Calculation==============================
        inValue = (iRed + iGreen + iBlue) / 3
        inArray[i][j] = inValue
        count += 1
        print(inValue, count)
# =============================================================================    

# =============================Hue Calculation=================================
        product = (hRed - hBlue) * (hGreen - hBlue)

        sqr = (hRed - hGreen) * (hRed - hGreen)
        denominator = math.sqrt(sqr + product)

        if denominator != 0:
            numerator = ((hRed - hGreen) + (hRed - hBlue)) / 2
            division = numerator / denominator

            radAngle = math.acos(division)
            degAngle = math.degrees(radAngle)

            if hBlue <= hGreen:
                hueValue = degAngle
                hueArray[i][j] = hueValue
            elif hBlue > hGreen:
                hueValue = 360 - degAngle
                hueArray[i][j] = hueValue
        elif denominator == 0:
            hueValue = 0
            hueArray[i][j] = hueValue
        #print(hueValue, count)
# =============================================================================

        j += 1
    i += 1 print(i, j)
```

PS. You will be seeing a lot of my amateur code in the future as well :D

Comment: Why not simply `HSVimage = img.convert('HSV')` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i tried that. The output of the image is same as the original image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what's going wrong now I am back at a computer. You probably tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

img    = Image.open('start.png')
hsvimg = img.convert('HSV')
hsvimg.save('result.png')
```

And if you do that, you actually get an error message:

```
OSError: cannot write mode HSV as PNG
```

because, PNG images are always in sRGB colourspace, so it correctly declines to write your HSV image. The thing is though, that the colourspace conversion actually worked and the values in the image actually are the HSV values that you want. You can check this with:

```
img.getpixel((X,Y))
```

and

```
hsvimg.getpixel((X,Y))
```

where `X` and `Y` are any random coordinates you like. You will see the the latter is always the correct HSV representation of the former's RGB colour.

I am not sure what you are trying to do overall, so I can't really advise properly, but one thing you could do is *"lie through your teeth"* and tell PIL/Pillow that the image is RGB even though you know it is HSV. So if you do:

```
hsvimg = img.convert('HSV')
hsvimg.mode='RGB'               # Tell PIL image is RGB
hsvimg.save('result.png')
```

it will save an image but it, and all other viewers, will show your Hue as Blue, your Saturation as Green and your Value as Blue.

I am guessing you have other processing to do, and this is only an intermediate aspect of your processing, so it probably won't matter and you can probably carry on and do your processing and convert back at the end and save to an sRGB PNG file without needing to lie.

---

In answer to your actual question, you can split and merge channels like this with PIL/Pillow:

```
# Split and recombine with PIL
r,g,b  = img.split()
merged = Image.merge(mode='RGB',bands=(r,g,b)))
```

Or, if you prefer Numpy which is often faster:

```
# Open image as Numpy array
img = np.array(Image.open('start.png'))
# Split into 3 channels/arrays/bands
r = img[:, :, 0]
g = img[:, :, 1]
b = img[:, :, 2]
# Recombine to single image
merged = np.dstack((r, g, b))
```

Comment: I created the HSV image like you instructed. Can i display just the hue content as an image? For example if i perform this action `h = npHSI[:, :, 0]` or `h, s, v = img.split()`, can I display **h** as an image? I tried doing that but the output is as same as the HSV image.

Comment: Sure. If you have a Numpy array, you can make a PIL Image with `PILim = Image.fromarray(h)` and then `PILim.show()`.